# What does this code mean that was placed in my hacked Web site?

Tags: security

My website was hacked, with the following code added to the end of the page:

```
<img heigth="1" width="1" border="0" 
    src="http://imgddd.net/t.php?id=########">
```

(The id had an 8 digit number in place of the ########)

The link didn't work.  Also, the page would crash until I removed the link. 
What else do I need to be worried about? Why would hackers put such a poor link on a website?

Comment: It is discussed here also:
http://wordpress.org/support/topic/invalid-rss-1?replies=30#post-2089161.
It seems it was an FTP hack of Filezilla. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 4):

`imgddd.net` shows up on [MalwareDomains.com](http://www.malwaredomains.com/)'s list (as of 4/26/2011) as a malware distributor; it appears as though the `t.php` script has been taken down, however, the main page remains active with what appears to be a Flash-based exploit; I'm not interested in seeing it in action, and would advise against testing it out yourself.

There are a variety of maliciously-crafted [image file exploits](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&source=hp&biw=1280&bih=814&q=image%20file%20buffer%20overflow&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=) in the wild - this was probably an attempt to launch one.

If your browser crashed, there is a possibility your machine was compromised by viewing the image file in question. Take appropriate precautions by scanning your machine for viruses, malware, and rootkits.

You will also need to audit your hosting account to determine how the malicious image link was added to your page - start by contacting your hosting provider.

Answer (score 2):

It is not enough to simply delete that snippet of code. And this is not what you do first.

- First you need to look for a newly added folder on your server called .log. Delete it.
- Then you need to delete one or two bogus .php files placed either on root or in subfolders
- Then you need to either delete a .htaccess folder placed on your server, or rewrite an existing one (please see
  http://blog.unmaskparasites.com/2011/05/05/thousands-of-hacked-sites-seriously-poison-google-image-search-results/
- Finally, you delete that code snippet you mention

Comment: I didn't find a .log file, or notice any recent suspicious files either. Strange.

Comment: @Ari, 
**1.** the .log directory and other doorway files are not always being created on hacked sites
**2.** the .log directory and .php files can be created in some subdirectory of your site, so make sure to scan them all for suspicius content
**3.** I confirm that this hack uses stolen FTP passwords.

Comment: and stop using FTP, start using SFTP